# Which characters are included in elastic search character groups (whitespace, letter, digit, punctuation, symbol)?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to build a tokenizer based on whitespaces and punctuation marks using a chargroup tokenizer. I found that there are, at least, [5 predefined **character groups**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-chargroup-tokenizer.html): `whitespace`, `letter`, `digit`, `punctuation`, `symbol`.

So, I tried the following tokenizer:

```
tokenizer": {
    "my_tokenizer": { 
       "type": "char_group", 
       "tokenize_on_chars":["whitespace", "punctuation"]
     }
}
```

Then, I realized that the `@` symbol is included in the `punctuation` character group which I need as part of the text (e.g. to capture Twitter screennames). I am not sure why `@` is considered a punctuation but my guess is that it can be seen as such in emails addresses? e.g. `email@example.com`.

Anyway, I ended adding them myself:

```
tokenizer": {
    "my_tokenizer": { 
       "type": "char_group", 
       "tokenize_on_chars":["whitespace", "\n", ".", ",", ";", ":", "\"", "`", "]", "[", ")", "(", "!", "?", "/", "\\", "–"]
     }
},
```

However that list looks rather arbitrary and not very elegant. **Where can I find the  definition of the different character groups in elastic search**? (or, is there a more elegant way to separate tokens based on an `standard` list of punctuation for English and German?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a look at the source code for this :

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/237650e9c054149fd08213b38a81a3666c1868e5/modules/analysis-common/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/analysis/common/CharMatcher.java

The `java.lang.Character` class is responsible for defining the constants like for instance :

```
Character.MODIFIER_SYMBOL : ` ^
Character.DASH_PUNCTUATION : -
Character.MATH_SYMBOL : = ~ + | < >
Character.OTHER_PUNCTUATION : !@#%&*;':",./?
Character.START_PUNCTUATION : ( [ {
Character.END_PUNCTUATION : ) ] }
```